# Java sorting list by element property with stream()

Tags: java, sorting, lambda, java-stream

```
public static List<Student> getStudents(List<Student> students) {
        return students.stream(). // rest of the code comes here.
}
```

I'd like to return a `List<Student>` which contains the students sorted in a descending order by their averages. I have to use lambda expression with the `stream()` method.

Example class:

```
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int birthYear;
    private double average;

    public Student(String name, int birthYear, double average) {
        this.name = name;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
        this.average = average;
    }
    ...getters and setters...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return statement can be as simple as:

```
return students.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Student::getAverage).reversed())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getAverage)` returns a comparator that compares student `average` fields (assuming getter), and `reversed()` reverses the natural order.